# Creating relational database

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

E diagram which i need to turn into databse. I know my primary keys but do not really understand how to link the different tables together.

So I have operator table with name as primary key. Each operator can operate certain proportion of those trains. e.g operator "a" 30 = 30% of those services and operator b 70% of those services  100 all of them etc...
This is the part im stuck with. Do I need another table to link these two tables together ?

for each train i need to store which station it starts from and where its going to terminate (destination) once again do i create new table for this ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your Operates box as a representation of your keys table with OperatorID/TrainID to associate operators with trains.

No, for train start and end stationIDs, you don't need another table, just fields in the Train table.

Is this homework?  Are these new concepts for you?

Comment: Yes its coursework. I understand sql and i did make databases before just not with proper relations which confuse me

Comment: try practicing with MS Access

Comment: well we are really just using queries to make this, part of exercise.I think ms access kinds of defeats the point because isnt it just click and drag etc... ?

Comment: Right yea I understand the Train to station relation now. But still confused about the Operates relationship. What did you mean by 
"You can use your Operates box as a representation of your keys table with OperatorID/TrainID to associate operators with trains."

Comment: think of the box labeled 'operates' in your diagram as a table with 2 fields, trainID and operatorID.  The PK of the operates table is both fields, and both fields individually have a FK relationship with train and operator.

Comment: What about the Proportion then ?

Comment: yeah, that would have to be entered in the Operates table, too, but not as part of the PK

Comment: Okay I am starting to understand now. I will be back late on today or tomorrow would appreciate if you would check this thread if its not too much to ask for. Thank you very much =)

Comment: look, if you're on LinkedIn, why don't you send me an invitation to connect?